# how to control the styles of an external component in angular with PHP?

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I try to change the css styles of an external component that I only consume in Angular

This is how I consume the component in the following way, I only pass some parameters

```
<payment-component id="paymentwindow" ng-if="paymentdata" id="collapseExample" name="paymentwindow" paymentorder={{paymentdata}} ></payment-component>
```

Everything works fine except for the CSS styles since I need to modify some colors and dimensions, in the inspector I get this legend

```
#shadow-root (open)
```

I have tried the following way and it doesn't work for me

```
<script>
class AppElement extends HTMLElement {
  builder() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
      <style>
        :host {
          /* Styles for the custom component */
          width: 400px;
          height: 200px;
          /* Add more styles as needed */
        }
      </style>
    `;

    // Rest of the configuration and content of the component
  }
}

customElements.define("payment-component", AppElement);
</script>
```

it gives me this error

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "payment-component" has already been used with this registry
```

I clarify that I am using php with Angular